# on click show div getting error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I click on the `div`, it should open. When I click again, it should close the `div`. Please help me on this.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var bool = 0;
            function showDiv(){
                if(bool==1){
                    bool=0;
                    document.getElementById(show).style.visibility = "hidden";
                }else if(bool==0){
                    bool=1;
                    document.getElementById(show).style.visibility = "visible";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="click" onclick="showDiv();" />

        <div="show">
            <p>it is okay it is okay it is okay it is okay it is okay it is okay it is okay it is okay</p>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I changed my mind on removing the jQuery tag because there are already answers using it... But if you tag jQuery make sure that your code is about jQuery or explicitly say you want a jQuery solution, otherwise it causes confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the quotes for the `id` argument for `getElementById()`

```
document.getElementById('show').style.visibility = "hidden";
```

Also the `id` attribute name is missing on the `<div>`

```
 <div="show">
```

Should be this:

```
<div id="show">
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/puEgC/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<button id="myButton">Show DIV</button>
<div id="show" class="hidden">
    <p>it is okay </p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hidden
{
  display:none;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('#myButton').click(function () {
        $("#show").slideToggle();
        $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Show DIV' ? 'Hide DIV' : 'Show DIV');
        return false;
});
```

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mgrcic/RbjLJ/

Answer (score 0):

When you are referring to

```
document.getElementById(show).style.visibility
```

The `show` refers to a **variable**, but you are trying to get it as a string, so you should get it quoted

```
document.getElementById('show').style.visibility
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, you couldn't get your element without specifying **`div id="theid"`**:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var bool = 0;
            function showDiv(){
            var elem = document.getElementById('show');
            console.log(elem);
                if(bool==1){
                    bool=0;
                    elem.style.visibility = "hidden";
                }else if(bool==0){
                    bool=1;
                    elem.style.visibility = "visible";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="click" onclick="showDiv();" />

        <div id="show">
            <p>it is okay it is okay it is okay it is okay it is okay it is okay it is okay it is okay</p>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are writing the div wrong. You should put "show" as the value of your Id attribute:

```
<div id="show"> </div>
```

If you use jQuery (you tagged it), why not use jQuery to get things done more cleanly, in an [unobtrusive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) way ?

```
$(function(){       
    var bool = 0;
    $("input[type='button']").click(function(){        
        if(bool ==0)
        {
            bool =1
            $("#show").hide();
        }
        else
        {
            bool =0
            $("#show").show();
        }
    });    
});
```

Here is the sample: http://jsfiddle.net/sHsuh/10/

Note that this script will bind the function to all button elements in your page. So I would be more specific by adding an Id to my Button and bind with that:

```
$("#myButtonId").click(function(){
  //code goes here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have made some mistakes:

1. `<div="show">` is wrong. The correct way is `<div id="show">`.
2. If you want show and hide means, first set your div's CSS to `visibility:hidden;`.
3. You are missing an apostrophe in `document.getElementById('show');`.

Try this:

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            var bool = 0;
                function showDiv(){
                    if(bool==1){
                        bool=0;
                        document.getElementById('show').style.visibility = "hidden";
                    }else if(bool==0){

                        bool=1;
                        document.getElementById('show').style.visibility = "visible";
                    }
                }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <input type="button" value="click" onclick="showDiv();" />

            <div id="show" style=" visibility:hidden;">
                <p>it is okay it is okay it is okay it is okay it is okay it is okay it is okay it is okay</p>
            </div>

        </body>
    </html>
```